# Interpretation of OR in logistic mixed model

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I am new to mixed models and am unsure about the interpretation of the OR results. I have a significant main effect of OR = 1.08, 95% CI [1.01, 1.16], p = 0.025.

How can I interpret this? The variable is a continuous variable that is increased the probability of a hit (binary outcome). So my best guess right now is that a one-unit increase in the continuous variable is associated with a 1.08 times higher chance of a hit.

I have also read that some people say that the probability of a hit increases 8% with a one-point increase of the continuous variable.

I am not sure if that is correct though. Can anyone be so kind to explain?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that! I will try to move the question.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  We have many good posts on odds ratios: here's a [focused search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=odds+ratio+logistic+expl*+score%3A10+is%3Aanswer).